# How can I optimize webpack build by splitting entry point?

Tags: javascript, webpack, optimization, build

I want to optimize my webpack build file and tried to use code splitting (https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/). The largest part of my application is vuetify and I try to separate it from my index.js
Here is my index.js file:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue';
import router from './router/router'
import vuetify from './plugins/vuetify'

new Vue({
    router,
    vuetify,
    el:'#vue-app',
    render: a => a(App)
})
```

vuetify is configurated in ./src/plugins/vuetify.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify/lib'

Vue.use(Vuetify)

const opts = {}

export default new Vuetify(opts)
```

and here is my webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin');

const VueLoaderPlugin = require('vue-loader/lib/plugin')

const VuetifyLoaderPlugin = require('vuetify-loader/lib/plugin')

module.exports = {
    // mode:'development',
    entry: {
        main: './src/index.js',
        vuetify: './src/plugins/vuetify.js',
    },
    output: {
        filename: '[name].bungle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    },
    plugins: [
        new CleanWebpackPlugin({ cleanStaleWebpackAssets: false }),

        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            title: 'Development',
            template:'./index.html'
        }),
        new VueLoaderPlugin(),
        new VuetifyLoaderPlugin()
    ],

    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.m?js$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: {
                        presets: ['@babel/preset-env'],
                        plugins: ['@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread']
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                //Правила для vue.js
                test: /\.vue$/,
                loader: 'vue-loader'
            },
            {
                // Правила для обработки css стилей
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [
                    'vue-style-loader',
                    'css-loader'
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.s(c|a)ss$/,
                use: [
                    'vue-style-loader',
                    'css-loader',
                    {
                        loader: 'sass-loader',
                        options: {
                            implementation: require('sass'),
                            sassOptions: {
                                fiber: require('fibers'),
                                indentedSyntax: true // optional
                            },
                        },
                    },
                ],
            },

        ]
    },

};
```

but when I run npm run build it makes two entry points:

```
Entrypoints:
  main (452 KiB)
      main.bungle.js
  vuetify (315 KiB)
      vuetify.bungle.js
```

With one entry point main.js is the same:
    Entrypoints:
      main (452 KiB)
          main.bungle.js
Looks like in result application vuetify is build in main.bungle.js and not imported from vuetify.bungle.js. Another solution is to lazy-loading, but I still want to do this by code-splitting.

Comment: Remove `vuetify` from your entry points, it's not an entry-point!

Comment: I know what you mean but how can I separate vuetify import from my index.js. I tried to make modules.js and transfer `import vuetify from './plugins/vuetify'` there to make two entry points. But with this solution result main.bungle.js couldn`t find vuetify. Or I am in the wrong way to optimize my application?

Comment: Best would be to create a little github sampe repo which shows the current state.
Usually webpack splits your bundles based on default settings, which should fit in most of the cases, but if you want to tweak it, you should use the SplitChunksPlugin. But create a little repo and I will have a look.

Comment: Here is my projects repo "https://github.com/Yakhnitsa/web-development_webpack.git". I tried to use `splitChunks: { chunks: 'all'}`, but I still can't get how can I split my application into a few entry points, such as vuetify, router, vuex. There are a little in documentation, and some things doesn't work to try them, such as this moment (https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/#entry-dependencies), the code `entry: {index: { import: './src/index.js', dependOn: 'shared' }} ` doesn't work, webpack tells that I can't use configuration object, only string or array.

Comment: And thank you for helping me with this.

Comment: As far as i can see, vuetify and vue are in one bundle and the other bundle contains your pages. Also when gzipped, the size is ok. Add this plugin to your repo: `webpack-bundle-analyzer`. For me your repo looks good. 

Here is the result: https://i.imgur.com/u3wDGks.png

Comment: Thank you for advice about webpack-bungle-analyzer, such a simple way to get a treemap of my application.

Comment: The last question if you don't mind. How can I configure splitChuncs in webpack to split my vendors~main.bungle.js into parts, now it contains all node_modules and it size a bit large, is there any way to split it for example into vuetify and vue/dist, or other parts?

Comment: Do you have pages, that don't use `vue` or `vuetify`? Then it might make sense to do that. You can try `dependon`: https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/#entry-dependencies